Equivalence between geometries of identical matter distributions
In Maxwell's EM, we have an uniqueness theorem for inhomogeneous solutions of the fields, given adequate boundary conditions.
I wonder in General Relativity, if we have two spacetimes with the same asymptotic flatness conditions, and one proves there is an equivalent mass distribution, what can be said about the spacetime solutions. I care only about static spacetimes in this case, which I presume avoids the problem of propagating modes.
The troubling issue I find here is properly defining what it means for mass distributions to be equivalent unless the metric is already known, which in this case one has already a specific solution at hand. I suppose one could say two distributions have the same shape by looking at their Weyl curvature tensor, but in a physical spacetime that should leave out some degrees of freedoms unspecified (such as magnitudes and ratios for densities and pressures of the matter distributions).
What are proper/better ways this problem should be approached?

As you note, uniqueness in GR is tricky to think about. What you're looking for is known as the Cauchy Problem, i.e. what are the conditions for the existence and uniqueness of solutions to Einstein Equations.
Maxwell Equations are a linear hyperbolic system of PDFs and existence and uniqueness proceed somewhat straightforwardly. Einstein Equations are non-linear hyperbolic PDFs, and here the non-linear is the source of difficulties.
One popular way to think about this is to frame the question in terms of the 3+1 decomposition. Start from a 3-dimensional space with a given space metric and a matter distribution. Then one can show that a unique 4-dimensional spacetime (of some properties) exists that is a solution of Einstein Equations and contains the original 3-dimensional space as a subspace. The properties in parentheses are that this spacetime is globally hyperbolic, which means it has a "good" causal structure, roughly that almost every event in this spacetime is in the past and future of some other event and that there are no closed time-like curves, so basically every event is causally connected and no time travel. Take my description as very loose though, because the issue of "good" causal structure has to take account of singularities such as those in black holes and cosmological models.
In your framing, if I have two equivalent mass distributions in a given space, then both have a unique spacetime that "develops" from it and satisfies Einstein Equations.
For further information, you could start by browsing the Wikipedia page for Yvonne Choquet-Bruhat, she was one of the pioneers of this whole existence and uniqueness game. Her book "Introduction to General Relativity, Blacks Holes and Cosmology" has a section devoted to the Cauchy Problem and general solutions to Einstein Equations. Graduate-level GR books usually contain at least an introduction to this topic, and I like Robert Wald's take on it. Alternatively one could look at any book on numerical relativity, as, unsurprisingly, the Cauchy problem is foundational for getting solutions to Einstein Equations from a computer.
